# C# one liner of .Length and IndexOf

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string number with @
I need this strings last 10 char without @ symbol. I am doing like this but is it possible with one liner or much easier?

```
string value = "901234567890@123.123.1.23";
string ani2 = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("@"));
string ani = ani2.Substring(ani2.Length - 10);
```

it should show "1234567890".

Comment: Are you happy enough with a Regex solution?

Comment: Is your input guaranteed to be longer than 10? If not, then no, you shouldn't do this in one line

Comment: Code golf?... You can easily pack all that into single line by inlining `ani2` like `value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("@")).Substring(value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("@")).Length - 10)`... but why would you want to do that? Maybe your goal is something else than do "one-liner"?

Comment: `value.Split("@")[0][^10..]` would do it (using slicing), but only if you know your strings will be at least 10 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle any length of input, Regex is maybe the easiest to do:

```
string value = "901234567890@123.123.1.23";
var result = Regex.Match(value, "(?<target>.{0,10})@").Groups["target"].Value;
// result = 1234567890
```

```
string value = "123@123.123.1.23";
var result = Regex.Match(value, "(?<target>.{0,10})@").Groups["target"].Value;
// result = 123
```

the pattern I'm using `(?<target>.{0,10})@")` is saying:

`.{0,10}` Match up to 10 characters

`.{0,10}@` Match  up to 10 characters that appear before an `@` symbol.

`(.{0,10})@` match up to 10 characters that appear before an `@` symbol, and give me those characters (excluding the `@`) in a group.

`(?<target>.{0,10})@` match up to 10 characters that appear before an `@` symbol, and give me those characters (excluding the `@`) in a group called `target`.

you could get away with the third option, but the fourth is easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how certain you are about the format of your input. This could work, if you know the first part has at least ten characters:

```
var result = value.Split("@")[0][^10..];
```

This uses the C# 8 [Range operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges).

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it.

Comment: Very cool, 99% of C# devs are going to have to google "caret in array accessor csharp" if they come across this in code, but they'll be smarter for it.